# Crystal Reports VS 2008 Different Wrapping Behavior

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, wordpad

I have a text box which is 7.5" wide and I set `Can Grow`. Inside the textbox I have placed a TEXT database field. I set the field to use the RTF format. When I export the report to PDF on the developer machine I am able to get the word wrapping where it should be (after the finagling with the right margin). However, when I export the report on the server, I get word wrapping about an inch sooner than on the development machine.

So here is some more information: the PDF of the report is generated by an ASP.NET application on both the development machine (from within VS 2008) and the server; I am using the Crystal Reports VS 2008 runtime.

I have tried a few ideas so far:

I found out that Wordpad does not save the page margins into the RTF document. It always uses the last used settings for the page margins which is 1.25" L-R and 1" T-B.

I tried editing the RTF source and adding the appropiate page margins: `\margl720\margr720\margt720\margb720` which sets all margins to 720 twips (0.5").

I tried setting the Wordpad defaults for the page margins to 0.5". This is different for each user though. I have the Application Pool for the ASP.NET application running as a specific user. I tried setting it under that user and no change. Is it possible that the Crystal Report is being generated under a different user? Or that Crystal Reports always uses a specific user for this information?

After the settings on the server had no effect, I set the margins on the development machine back to the default and re-ran the report. This causes the report to have the same problem as on the server. So it has to be something with the Wordpad page margins.

So the question is: how do I get these settings set for the server? Or how can I figure out under which user the Crystal Report is being generated?

Comment: Have you noticed any difference in font sizes between the client and the server?  If so, it may be related to the default printer.  Crystal Reports seems to base its font size on whatever printer driver is installed, even when you are exporting to a PDF.

Comment: I had forgotten that I also changed the report printer to `No Printer`. That is what actually caused the problem to appear on the development machine. So I guess now the question is how to get Crystal Reports to wrap the RTF text at the correct location when `No Printer` is selected? Or is there a good printer to select as the default that would allow consistency between the development machine and the server?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it had to do with the printer drive as Paul suggested. To fix the issue I changed the report to use `No Printer`. This did not solve the weird wrapping of the RTF by Crystal Reports. To fix that I made the text box that the field was in wider than the page. I had to find how far off the page by trial and error.